# Brezis' Exercise 4.10.3: can we pick such a measurable $u_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Let $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $j:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be convex. We define
> $$
> J:L^p(\Omega) \to (-\infty,+\infty], u \mapsto \int_\Omega j \circ u.
> $$
> Let $p'$ be the Hölder conjugate of $p$, i.e., $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} =1$. Let $j^*:\mathbb R \to (-\infty,+\infty]$ and $J^*: L^{p'}(\Omega) \to (-\infty,+\infty]$ the [convex conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate?useskin=vector#Definition) of $j$ and $J$ respectively. Prove that
> $$
> J^*(f) = \int j^* \circ f \quad \forall f \in L^{p'}(\Omega).
> $$

My below attempt would be complete if I could pick such a **measurable $u_n$**. Could you elaborate on how to finish my proof?

---

**My attempt** Notice that $j$ is continuous, so $j^*$ is measurable. Fix $f \in L^{p'}(\Omega)$. By definition,
$$
J^*(f) := \sup_{u \in L^p (\Omega)} \int ( fu - j \circ u).
$$

Clearly,
$$
f(\omega) u(\omega) - j (u (\omega)) \le \sup_{t \in \mathbb R} (f(\omega) t- j(t)) = j^* \circ f(\omega)
\quad \forall \omega \in \Omega.
$$

Hence $J^*(f) \le \int j^* \circ f$. Let's prove the reverse. WLOG, we assume $J^*(f)$ is finite. Let $B_n := \{t \in \mathbb R : |t| \le n\}$. Then $B$ is compact. Notice that $j$ is continuous. We define
$$
\varphi_n:\mathbb R \to (-\infty, +\infty], x \mapsto \max_{t \in B_n} (x t- j(t)).
$$

Then for every $x \in \mathbb R$, we have $\varphi_n (x) \uparrow j^* (x)$ as $n \to \infty$. For each $(n, \omega) \in \mathbb N^* \times \Omega$, there is (not necessarily unique) $u_n (\omega) \in B_n$ such that
$$
\varphi_n \circ f(\omega) = f(\omega) u_n (\omega) - j(u_n (\omega)).
$$

Clearly, $u_n:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is bounded. We now **assume $u_n$ is measurable**. Because $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, we get $u_n \in L^p (\Omega)$. So
$$
\int \varphi_n \circ f = \int  ( fu_n - j \circ u_n) \le J^* (f).
$$

We have  $\varphi_n \circ f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ and $\varphi_n \circ f \le \varphi_{n+1} \circ f$ for all $n$. By [monotone convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672101/let-f-n-subset-l1-omega-such-that-f-n-le-f-n1-and-sup-n-int-f-n),
$$
\int j^* \circ f  = \lim_n \int \varphi_n \circ f  \le J^* (f).
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Are you taking your functions strictly convex? If so then $u_n$ is well defined, if not, I think multiple maximising points can exist

Comment: @FShrike I just pick one among those maximizers.

Comment: @FShrike Please see my answer if you're interested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that such measurable selection is possible in our case. It follows from below [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555588/measurable-argmax-correspondence-on-probability-spaces), i.e.,

---

Let $X$ be a polish space and $(S,\Sigma)$ a measurable space. Let $\varphi: S \twoheadrightarrow X$ be a weakly measurable correspondence with nonempty compact values, and suppose that $f: S \times X \to \mathbb{R}$  is a Caratheodory function (measurable in $s$ and continuous in $x$). Define the value function $m$ by:
$$
m(s) = \max_{x \in \varphi(s)} f(s,x),
$$
and the correspondence
$$
\mu(s) = \{ x \in \varphi(s): f(s,x) = m(s) \}.
$$
Then:

- The value function $m$ is measurable.
- The argmax correspondence $\mu$ is measurable, has nonempty compact values and **admits a measurable selector**.

Clarification: By weakly measurable correspondence is meant that $\{s \in S: \varphi(s) \cap K \neq \emptyset \}$ belongs to $\Sigma$ for each compact set $K$.

Comment: You have a measurable ‘correspondence’ $\mu$ but can you be certain of converting it into a measurable function?

Comment: @FShrike Maybe I miss-understand your comment, but "The argmax correspondence $\mu$ is measurable, has nonempty compact values and *admits a measurable selector*".

Comment: Ah I didn’t see that bit!

Comment: I would hope Brezis expected an easier solution, seems like a nontrivial theorem to use here

Comment: @FShrike My solution actually is quite straightforward and easier than Brezis' which appeals to two other exercises about regularization by inf-convolution. In fact, Brezis does *not* justify why his $u_n$ is measurable. You can have a look at his solution at page 395 [here](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf).

Comment: But it is not straightforward to check the existence of a measurable selector, right? I mean, the linked post doesn’t seem to prove that.

Comment: @FShrike Yess it is not straightforward...